# Unicode characters not showed when bundling and deploying React app with webpack and babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

On my local environment, unicode characters work fine but when I run webpack to bundle and deploy, string which is like "\uf00c" becomes "" in index_bundle.js

I think there's a problem in babel config or webpack config but I can't resolve it as I'm new to the whole stack.

Here is the codes:

```
<Label className="switch switch-icon switch-pill switch-success">
   <Input type="checkbox" className="switch-input" defaultChecked onChange={this.handleActivateUser.bind(this, user.id)}/>
      <span className="switch-label" data-on={'\uf00c'} data-off={'\uf00d'}></span>
      <span className="switch-handle"></span>
</Label>
```

My .babelrc:

```
{
   "presets": [
     ["env"], ["react"]
   ],
   "plugins": ["transform-class-properties", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

And my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].fonts.css');
const extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].styles.css');
const webpackUglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack-uglify-js-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
config = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', './app/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
          test: /\.(scss)$/,
          use: ['css-hot-loader'].concat(extractSCSS.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {alias: {'../img': '../public/img'}}
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader'
              }
            ]
          }))
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: extractCSS.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: 'css-loader'
          })
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          use: [
            {
              // loader: 'url-loader'
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: './img/[name].[hash].[ext]'
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              // loader: 'url-loader'
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: './fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    }),
    extractCSS,
    extractSCSS,
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: './public/img', to: 'img'}
      ],
      {copyUnmodified: false}
    )
  ]
}
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution. You need to set your javascript file `UTF-8`. You could either do

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="xyz.js"></script>
```

or

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  ...
</head>
```

for all your HTML files

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44907641/2075423

Comment: This also worked for a case where console was crying something like `unexpected character/token`. In `js` file there was this `Ë†:"circ",Ë‡:"caron"` - as You can see the double quote of the json keys were missing. Magically after adding the `charset="UTF-8"`  it worked out.