# Utf-8 text in javascript not showing properly when served by Glassfish

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, struts2, glassfish-4

My script is saved in uft-8 encoded file:

**test.js**

```
function sayhi(){

    alert('Γειά σου!')

}
```

**In html file (also utf-8) I got** :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script charset="utf-8"  type="text/javascript" src="../js/mytest.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('Γειά!')
                sayhi();
    <script type="text/javascript">
 </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that `sayhi` which is supposed to print `utf-8` string - prints an unreadable string  as opposed to alert above it (`alert('Γειά!')`) which prints the correct string.

What am I missing? How to make the `sayhi` use the correct encoding. 
Thanks.

PS. The page is served by glassfish app server (not sure if that matters)

**Edit 1:**

Also in my **glassfish-web.xml** I have declared

```
 <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Anything else I could do in glasfish to serve javascript correctly?

**Edit 2:**

I failed to mention that I am also using `struts2` and `jersey` and something tells me that `struts 2` is the culprit here. I am thinking that may be an implementation of  some filters to change the encoding or a strust directive to ignore the path with javacript may solve the issue... will try the above later.

Comment: Look at the HTTP Content-Type headers your JS file is served with.

Comment: have you tried setting the encoding for the html file `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in `<head>`?

Comment: @Peter Pajchi  I have already  <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> (a jsp tag which I suppose is enough) any way meta tag did't help

Comment: @deceze any tip how to do that - I am looking at headers from chrome dev tools ... can't see any   Content-Type header though ...

Comment: That may be the issue. If your server isn't setting the header, the browser may interpret it in whatever encoding it feels like.

Comment: @deceze so, if I understand you correctly - this must be application server / glassfish  settings issue?

Comment: That would be my best guess, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding a filter to my **web.xml**

```
public class CharsetFilter implements Filter
{
 public static final String DESIRED_ENCODING="UTF-8";
 private String encoding;

 @Override
 public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException
 {
   encoding = config.getInitParameter("appEncoding");
   if( encoding==null ) encoding=DESIRED_ENCODING;
 }

 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next)
 throws IOException, ServletException
 {
  //HttpServletRequest rq=(HttpServletRequest)request;  
  //String uri=rq.getRequestURI().toLowerCase();  
  //System.out.println(""+uri);
  //this is used to fix static javascript encoding 
  if (!encoding.equals(response.getCharacterEncoding())){
    response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
  }
  if (!encoding.equals(request.getCharacterEncoding())){
    request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
  }

  next.doFilter(request, response);
 }

 public void destroy(){}
}
```

and in **web.xml**:

```
        <filter>
        <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>utilities.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>appEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a charset for the script tag or the script itself - a charset on the HTML page will suffice. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44907641) for more info. All you need to add is this, on your HTML page and in the head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8 />
```

And it should work.

Comment: Since the `alert` within the same page already works, I'd be surprised if this made any difference.

Comment: I think that the linked answr said that this worked for the external files, but it didn't mention internal fi
les not working.

Comment: I have already <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> (a jsp tag which I suppose is enough) any way I tried adding meta tag too -  did't help